# How can I reuse templates in Vue 2?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have two forms (add and edit). All the fields in both of the forms are exactly the same (i.e. the templates are the same). Both the forms are accessible from the homepage through their respective buttons. How can I reuse a single Vue template for **Add form** as well as **Edit form**?

I am writing class based components in TypeScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a component called `customform` or something, then declare props that will be passed into the component to specify what type it is (edit form, create form) then inside the form you'll need to write your logic, something like this:

```
<customForm :edit="true" :create="false" :data="data"></customForm>
```

Then in the form component:

```
<template>
  <form class="customform">
    <div class="row">
      <label>Email: </label><input type="text" value="{{data.email || ''}}">
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    edit: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    create: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    data: {}
  }
}
</script>
```

**The Idea** is to be able to render the form using props (e.g if edit is true then you will have to inject the values and change the action of the form, if create then the value of the fields will be empty and the action will be different...etc)